# Another issue with tiny_mce and django

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I am a noob, and this isn't a problem actually. My tiny_mce works great on django development server, but doesn't work on production server. I think it has something to do with url configuration, because I get this error trying to fetch tiny_mce from source code of the page in browser:

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://sav.2eng.ru/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
    "templates/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" does not exist
```

I used this tutorial: http://vimeo.com/12903891
My url config is:

```
    (r'^js/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root' : 'templates/js'}),
```

and it works fine with 'manage.py runserver'.

admin.py has following code:

```
    class AboutPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [AboutPageImageInline,]    
        list_display = ('p',)
        class Media:
        js = ('/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', '/js/textareas.js')
```

What am I supposed to do with this url?
Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding abslolute, not relative path. I'll never forget this. Hope this would be usefull for someone.